# Strange BigDecimal value using DecimalFormat

Tags: java, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I'm trying to convert some string values in number using DecimalFormat. I try to explain you my problem in a better way:

I have the following method:

```
private BigDecimal loadBigDecimal(String value){

    BigDecimal bigDecimalToReturn = null;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
    bigDecimalToReturn = new BigDecimal(df.parse(value).doubleValue());
    return bigDecimalToReturn;
}
```

Now if I try to run the method:

```
BigDeciaml dec = myObject.loadBigDecimal("120,11");
```

The value of dec is `120.1099999999999994315658113919198513031005859375`.
Why decimalFormat is changing the scale of my value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing conversion to double and backwards. That's unnecessary and introduces rounding errors. You should use the following code:

```
private BigDecimal loadBigDecimal(String value) throws ParseException {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
    df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
    return (BigDecimal) df.parse(value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Doubles are only approximations. That is correct for a double. If you want a specific scale, you need to tell it in the BigDecimal constructor.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the `df.parse(value).doubleValue()` call. At this point, the value is converted to a double.

double represent plus or minus the sum of powers of 2 (with positive and negative exponents).

One can write 120 as 64+32+16+8.

But one can't write 0.11 as a finite sum of power of 2.

So there is an approximation.

0.1099999999999994315658113919198513031005859375

Which is a sum of power of 2.

It's look like BigDecimal as a [constructor with a string for parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29). Maybe you can just use it.

```
BigDecimal dec = new BigDecimal("120,11");
```